# Visual Studio 2010 new project wizard manufactured MFC Dialog program doesn't compile in Debug Mode?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mfc, build, projects-and-solutions, wizard

I've created a new project using the Visual Studio 2010's wizard. Once VS was finished generating the project I tried building it - in release mode it worked great, but in debug mode it didn't, giving the following compiler error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: MyProj, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 05/10/2010 22:17:08.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "Debug\MyProj.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>ResourceCompile:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>ManifestResourceCompile:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'D:\My Documents\Dev\MyProj\MyProj\Debug\MyProj.exe'
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.24
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I set the following parameters in the wizard:

- MFC Application
- Dialog based
- Use MFC in a static library
- Added the "Windows Sockets" advanced feature

I'm on a Windows 7 64bit Ultimate machine.

Comment: Get use to Microsoft product... especially newly product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a minor bug in Visual Studio 2010. Once I closed the solution and reopened it, it worked fine...
This error is reproducible on my setup.